# Solidity Yul nested mappings in storage

Tags: solidity, yul

I'm trying to save in storage some values in a nested mapping.
Found some results of a similar problem, tried the solutions, but no success, also read the documentation of https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/internals/layout_in_storage.html but still did not figured out what is wrong.

This is the complete code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Spiral {
    struct Chunk {
        int256 x;
        int256 y;
    }

    // 0: right, 1: down, 2: left, 3: up
    bytes1 directionB = 0x00;
    uint256 currentTravel = 1;
    uint256 stepCounter = currentTravel;

    Chunk[] public chunks;
    mapping(int256 => mapping(int256 => uint256)) public XYtoChunkId;

    constructor() {
        // Start the spiral at the origin (0, 0)
        chunks.push(Chunk(0, 0));
        XYtoChunkId[0][0] = 0;
    }

    function addChunk() public {
        int256 x;
        int256 y;
        uint256 chunkId;
        assembly {
            let r := sload(chunks.slot)
            mstore(0x00, chunks.slot)
            let chunks_pt := keccak256(0x00, 0x20)
            let p := add(mul(sub(r, 1), 2), chunks_pt)
            x := sload(p)
            y := sload(add(p, 1))

            let new_r := add(r, 1)
            let new_p := add(mul(r, 2), chunks_pt)

            sstore(chunks.slot, new_r)
            switch sload(directionB.slot)
            case 0x00 {
                sstore(new_p, add(x, 1))
                sstore(add(new_p, 1), y)
            }
            case 0x01 {
                sstore(new_p, x)
                sstore(add(new_p, 1), sub(y, 1))
            }
            case 0x02 {
                sstore(new_p, sub(x, 1))
                sstore(add(new_p, 1), y)
            }
            case 0x03 {
                sstore(new_p, x)
                sstore(add(new_p, 1), add(y, 1))
            }

            sstore(stepCounter.slot, sub(sload(stepCounter.slot), 1))
            if eq(sload(stepCounter.slot), 0x00) {
                sstore(
                    directionB.slot,
                    addmod(sload(directionB.slot), 0x01, 0x04)
                )
                sstore(stepCounter.slot, sload(currentTravel.slot))
                switch sload(directionB.slot)
                case 0x01 {
                    sstore(
                        currentTravel.slot,
                        add(sload(currentTravel.slot), 1)
                    )
                }
                case 0x03 {
                    sstore(
                        currentTravel.slot,
                        add(sload(currentTravel.slot), 1)
                    )
                }
            }

            mstore(0x00, x)
            mstore(0x20, XYtoChunkId.slot)
            let xHash := keccak256(0x00, 0x40)
            mstore(0x00, y)
            mstore(0x20, xHash)
            let chunkIdSlot := keccak256(0x00, 0x40)

            chunkId := sload(chunkIdSlot)
            sstore(chunkIdSlot, sub(r, 2))
        }
        console.log(chunkId);
        // XYtoChunkId[x][y] = chunks.length - 2;
    }
}
```

I am trying to add the `chunkId` which is `r - 2` in the mapping storage `mapping(int256 => mapping(int256 => uint256)) public XYtoChunkId;` using this part of the code

```
mstore(0x00, x)
mstore(0x20, XYtoChunkId.slot)
let xHash := keccak256(0x00, 0x40)
mstore(0x00, y)
mstore(0x20, xHash)
let chunkIdSlot := keccak256(0x00, 0x40)

chunkId := sload(chunkIdSlot)
sstore(chunkIdSlot, sub(r, 2))
```

Adapted this part from a similar question on the forum, no success, also tried to play around and switching order of x and y when keccak256, was getting some id's back , but not the correct ones. Thanks.

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by "no success", are you implying that `sstore` instruction doesn't save the value at specified location? that's not true

Comment: `sstore` gets the location and value from the stack, where are you pushing it?

Comment: by no success i mean when i console log chunkId i get 0 , instead of real values.
sstore saves to storage if i'm not wrong, sload gets the value from the storage.
The last part of the code that i mentioned should produce the same result as XYtoChunkId[x][y] = chunks.length - 2; but it does not. 
After executing the function and calling XYtoChunkId[x][y] I get 0 back instead of a real Id

Comment: run a trace and verify that the stack contains correct location and value just before SSTORE opcode is executed.  if you store some value but get 0 when reading it, then it means you are giving it wrong location either at write or read operation

Comment: please stop, you're not helping,
of course it's the wrong location i mentioned that i'm using the formula provided in the docs to calculate the storage location of a nested mapping, but value it's not getting inserted there

Answer (score 0):

It is zero because in the constructor you stored zero `XYtoChunkId[0][0] = 0`.

```
chunkId := sload(chunkIdSlot)
sstore(chunkIdSlot, sub(r, 2))
```

If you want to get the updated value, you have to read the slot after the modification

```
sstore(chunkIdSlot, sub(r, 2))   // <--- modification
chunkId := sload(chunkIdSlot).   // <--- read
```